# Error: RPC failed; curl 55 The requested URL returned error: 401 when pushing to GIT from R Studio

Tags: github, rstudio, git-push, rstudio-server

I can't push from R Studio and I keep getting the error:

> error: RPC failed; curl 55 The requested URL returned error: 401
>
> fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
>
> fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
>
> Everything up-to-date

Comment: It is possible that you have pushed a large file (>100MB). You need to unstage current changes, add that file to .gitignore and push again. To unstage, use `git reset HEAD~1 --soft`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I have dig in to the commits and found out that I had mistakenly committed a very large file which failed the push.

I have used `git log origin..HEAD` in my Ubuntu 18.04 AWS EC2 console to see that there are old commits there that haven't been pushed.

I have `git reset HEAD~1 --soft` to reset these two commits and corrected the files I want to commit and push in my R-Studio Server.

That's all the story, hope it will help others that have similar issues.

Comment: i get this error: fatal: ambiguous argument 'origin..HEAD': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.

Answer (score 7):

I had the same issue. And increasing the size of the http.postbuffer with this command fixed my issue:

```
git config --global http.postbuffer 2097152000
```

https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Bitbucket-questions/BitBucket-Disconnects-During-Long-Upload-Downloads/qaq-p/1170485

Answer (score 4):

This happened to me a couple times when pushing my code to github, just because my internet connection was too slow. I did have a medium-sized file (a couple MBs) which slowed things down, but it was simply resolved by trying again later when my connection improved.